# How can I display different content on different screens in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, ios13, external-display

I have an app that will need to connect to an external display, and I want to  display different content on both screens (not just mirror the iPad screen).

I have tried adding a Scene Configuration in my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Main</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>External Screen</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExtSceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Ext</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I also added a switch to return the correct `UISceneConfiguration` for each screen.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    switch connectingSceneSession.role.rawValue {
    case "UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication":
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    case "UIWindowSceneSessionRoleExternalDisplay":
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "External Screen", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    default:
        fatalError("No such role, I think? \(connectingSceneSession.role.rawValue)")
    }
}
```

While the breakpoint I have set in the above code in `configurationForConnecting` in my `AppDelegate` is called when I connect the  external screen, my app still simply mirrors the iPad screen.

I tried following [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/displaying_content_on_a_connected_screen?language=objc), but since iOS 13 the `screen` setter is deprecated, and this code does not work.

I really don't know how I can display different content on different physical screens, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

The answer by rmaddy was partially correct, the `configurationForConnecting` code was unnecessary. But there was a mistake in my `Info.plist`. The mistake was that I assigned both configurations to the `UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication` role. It should have been like this:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Main</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleExternalDisplay</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>External Screen</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExtSceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Ext</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Where the external screen configuration sits under the `UIWindowSceneSessionRoleExternalDisplay` key.

This works like a charm. I did have to add this code to the `willConnectTo` in my `ExtSceneDelegate` to make it fill the screen:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    windowScene.screen.overscanCompensation = .none
}
```

Comment: Good catch. I looked at your Info.plist many times and didn't notice that mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to setup the scene configurations in Info.plist, don't implement the `configurationForConnecting` UIApplicationDelegate method. So start by commenting out that method.

Given your Info.plist setup for the scene configuration, a window scene will automatically be created for the external screen. An instance of your `ExtSceneDelegate` class will be created for you, and it will be connected with your "Ext" storyboard.

Check the console for any errors. If there is any problem with your scene configuration or the external storyboard, you will only see a mirror of your main storyboard and not the external storyboard.

Also make sure your implementation of `willConnectTo` in your `ExtSceneDelegate` isn't doing anything to prevent the proper scene setup. The default implementation that does nothing is all you need to have your external storyboard connected to the automatically created window on the external screen.